# Dot product of csr_matrix causes segmentation fault

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have two (scipy) CSR sparse matrices:

```
A (12414693, 235470)
B (235470, 48063)
```

Performing:

```
A.dot(B)
```

causes a segmentation fault.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've submitted a bug to the scipy developer community:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3212

Comment: But these are **sparse** matrices, and so is the result. In fact, the result is supposed to be smaller than A (in terms of dimensions).

Comment: As @larsmans suggested in a comment that is now gone, the product of sparse matrices can result in drastic fill-in and give a densely populated matrix.  That might not be the problem here.  The seg. fault indicates a bug somewhere in the scipy code. It could be the result of a mishandled memory allocation failure, or something else.

Comment: Matrix A is a row-matrix of "one hot" vectors, so the result shouldn't be too dense.
Is this something worth reporting to the scipy developer community?

Comment: Yes, definitely; click on the green "New Issue" button here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues.  Be sure to mention the version of scipy that you are using (`import scipy; scipy.__version__`).

Comment: Extreme case: in your "one hot" encoding in A, suppose *all* the 1s are in column k.  And suppose in B, all the values in row k are nonzero, and those are the only nonzero values.  Then both A and B are very sparse, but the product is fully populated with nonzero values.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is very likely being caused by an overflow of an index stored in an `int32`, caused by the result of your dot product having more than 2^31 non-zero entries. Try the following...

```
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> c = np.empty_like(A.indptr)
>>> scipy.sparse.sparsetools.csr_matmat_pass1(A.shape[0], B.shape[1], A.indptr,
                                              A.indices, B.indptr, B.indices, c)
>>> np.all(np.diff(c) >= 0)
```

With your data, The array `c` is a vector of `12414693 + 1` items, holding the accumulated number of non-zero entries per row in the product of your two matrices, i.e. it is what `C.indptr` will be if `C = A.dot(B)` finishes successfully. It is of type `np.int32`, even on 64 bit platforms, which is not good. If your sparse matrix is too large, there will be an overflow, that last line will return `False`, and the arrays to store the result of the matrix product will be instantiated with a wrong size (the last item of `c`, which is very likely to be a negative number if an overflow did happen). If that's the case, then yes, file a bug report...

Comment: Nice.  Whether or not that is the case, he should file a bug report.  scipy code shouldn't seg. fault.

Comment: I'm not comfortable enough with C++ to be sure, but if the issue is as I describe it, then replacing a lot of `int`s with `npy_intp`s or `ssize_t`s should be all that's needed to do away with the issue.

Comment: Things aren't always as simple as one hopes: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1833, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/442

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, so it is a design and not a bug? One just has to know that `scipy.sparse` matrices can't hold more than `2 ** 31` none-zero elements.

Comment: The seg. fault is a bug.  The limit of 2**31 non-zero elements is a limitation of the current implementation.  In the pull request linked above, @pv. is working on removing that limitation.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, thanks, got it. It would be A LOT better if there was an explicit error message stating: scipy.sparse matrices can't hold more than 2 ** 31 none-zero elements.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, I think your comments, provide the best answer, maybe your should pull them together and post a separate answer.

Comment: @Jaime, thanks for the answer. I ran your suggested code, and it actually returned `True`.

Answer (score 2):

This link may be helpful: < http://blog.newsle.com/2013/02/01/text-classification-and-feature-hashing-sparse-matrix-vector-multiplication-in-cython/ >. The product of these will be too large. I'm not sure if the advice of the article applies for you, but you may try organizing the second matrix as a CSC type.

Comment: Isn't the advice of the article exactly the opposite? If your second matrix is in CSC format, it will be converted to CSR before multiplication, and that may blow up memory use.

Comment: No. It does argue that using CSR-to-CSC *in pure NumPy* will have a bad running time, but the article is about making a Cython implementation of one's own CSR-to-CSC multiplication. It is advocating for CSC format for the second matrix, just not directly in NumPy. E.g. the section titled "Sparse CSR/CSC Multiplication in Cython"